# Inject code just after Body tag

Tags: hooks, 10

I need to inject some code inside of **head** and **body** tags.

I managed to add code inside of **head** using **hook_page_attachments_alter** but I can't do same for Body.

Can somebody point me into right direction?

I am trying to inject a **iframe** just after **body** tag so it is like

```
<body><iframe>....</body>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The body tag is rendered using the theme's Twig template, usually `html.html.twig`. So the natural option would be do add it there.

See e.g. https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/11.x/core/themes/olivero/templates/layout/html.html.twig?ref_type=heads

Since the `<body>` tag (and whatever is following immediatly after the body tag) is hard-coded in the theme's Twig file, you most likely will no be able to inject this this programmatically with a hook.